# Hive View native support for HDInsight 4.0

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight

As per the [release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-release-notes) there is a ***native*** support for Hive View in HDIndight 4.0. I don't get this, it's there in HDInsight 3.6 as well -- so why is it called out explicitly in the release notes for HDI 4.0 ? And yes in HDI 3.6  also it appears natively , as soon as we spin a cluster and start Ambari, it's there already very much accessible. So how is it different in HDI 4.0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** Previously Hive view is not built-in for 4.0 clusters, and now product team added it back. That’s the reason it is being explicitly called out "Hive View is supported natively for HDInsight 4.0 clusters starting from this release. It doesn't apply to existing clusters. You need drop and recreate the cluster to get the built-in Hive View."

---

Thanks for bringing this to our attention. This question seems like a feedback on the document and not a specific question on the product.

In order to get your feedback addressed. I would request you to Submit feedback on the document.

How to submit a Azure document feedback?

**Step1:** Open the document which you are referring to.

**Step2:** Scroll down to the bottom of the page and click on "This page".

[image]

**Step3:** Enter your feedback title and issue.

[image]

Comment: It was a question. I am simply asking if there is a specific reason it's explicitly called out in the release document for HDI 4.0 ? But now based on your response it appears that it's probably a mistake in release note and then in that case the answer to my question is that -- No , there is no difference.

Comment: As per the product team response, I had updated the answer.